# i want to study win32 programming

Tags: c++

i want to study win32 programming(windows form applications) please advise me good sites or good book   (language c++)

Comment: What programming experience do you have right now? What languages and technologies do you know? You need to elaborate on your background so we can provide material that is suitable for someone of you level of expertise.

Comment: i know c++  at good level also basic algorithms and data structures

Comment: possible duplicate of [Book Recommendation for Winforms Design & Programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357545/book-recommendation-for-winforms-design-programming)

Comment: davit-datuashvili is also asking for sites - Not quite the same question

Comment: I think some research into previous highly related questions would be very helpful for davit-datuashvili.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Window form applications generally refers to .NET (C#, VB.NET, etc).  However, if you want to do win32 windows applications, this is a solid introduction, which I used when learning:

- http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/

**Edit:**

Now that I think about it, I also learned Win32 from this source, which is free, and available online:

- http://www.relisoft.com/book/

Comment: do you  hav electrical version of this book?i have problem with money and  can't buy

Comment: @davit-datuashvili: I don't, unfortunately, though you did ask for good books :)  Your question did remind me of another free resource, though.  Will edit my post to include it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the guy we all learned C++ from:

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/

I'm a new user here, so I can't post another link, but look at his FAQ for ideas on how to learn C++.

Comment: I think he wants to learn Win32, He says he is good with the C++.

Answer (score 1):

C Only
http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/
http://www.functionx.com/win32/index.htm
http://zetcode.com/tutorials/winapi/

C and C++
http://www.tenouk.com/abouttenouk.html